# About Frameworks (concept)

Tags: java, node.js, frameworks

Recently I saw a question about "Frameworks", if have different types or concepts for "Frameworks".
So, exist different "types" of "Frameworks"?

For example:
NodeJS is a '**type**' (concept) and Hibernate ORM is a other '**type**' (concept) ?

Or the word 'Framework' simply is a **definition**?

Answer (score 1):

When I hear the word "framework", I think of a code that sits on top of a "platform" to make it easier to accomplish some goal with the "platform".

For example, I would call Node a platform for running javascript on the server. Node contains all the features needed to run a web application server, but there are frameworks like Express, Hapi, Koa, etc. that make this easier.

Another example is the Ruby platform, which has the Ruby On Rails framework for creating MVC Web applications.

Comment: Ok John Oerter, thank for answer.
But Frameworks don't have categoires ?

Comment: What do you mean by categories? Do you mean the type of problem they are designed to solve? Like web applications, console applications, testing, etc.?

Comment: Yes! Jonh Oerter
You is right, this is my real question